# add clockoverlay in pipeline & correct use of capsfilter

Tags: c, gstreamer

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,format=\(fourcc\)YUY2,width=320,height=240,frame=25/1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=10/1 ! clockoverlay ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I am writing program using gstreamer-0.10 based on the gstreamer-0.10 command shown above.

There are couple of things on which I am completely clueless.

1) ***how to use clockoverlay*** and add it in pipeline ? I know its cap filter but couldnt able to find example for it?

2) ***Where to correctly add caps for videorate***. I mean,  I add after ffmpegcolourspace element and it works fine. For curiosity, I add it after ffenc_mpeg4 element  and again it works fine. I can see live video in both cases. Is it possible may be I am not adding it in pipeline at all. Can someone please advice me. Below is my snippet of code.

```
     source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
       // cap filter #1
       GstElement *capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "camera_caps");
       GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)YUY2,width=320,height=240,framerate=25/1");
       g_object_set (capsfilter, "caps", caps, NULL);

       conv = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "Colorconverter");

// capfilter #2
       GstElement *capsfilterColor = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "video-rate");
       GstCaps *capsColor = gst_caps_from_string ("videorate ! video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=10/1");
       g_object_set ( capsfilterColor, "caps", capsColor, NULL);


       videoenc = gst_element_factory_make("ffenc_mpeg4", "videoenc");

       udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink");

       // Create the empty pipeline
        pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

      g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink),
                    "host", "127.0.0.1",
                     "port", 5000,
                     NULL);


      g_object_set (G_OBJECT ( source ), "device", "/dev/video0", NULL);

      gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, capsfilter, conv, capsfilterColor,  videoenc, udpsink, NULL);

     // **here AM I adding caps filter correctly??**?
      gst_element_link_many (source, capsfilter, conv, capsfilterColor, videoenc, udpsink, NULL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1, To add clock overlay just put it somewhere after v4l2src(maybe its correct where you have it already).. the clockoverlay is just another element as v4l2src or videorate..

This is also working(I do not have 0.10 installed, but it should work):

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! clockoverlay ! autovideosink
```

2, To the code - its quite messy, you are mixing caps with elements. You have to understand that capsfilter is element which is there to impose some format on output of previous element.. the actual caps are set to capsfilter as property (on v4l2src you are setting properties like device etc.. on capsfilter you are setting property called `caps` with string representing those capabilities).

You cannot put videorate inside caps in that way... videorate is element, caps are properties..

you have to create videorate and add capsfilter after it.. so that videorate will convert the video stream to desired rate which it sees on its src pad(the output of videorate).

So the code would be as below.
Sorry I couldnt resit to tidy up a bit, also renamed capsfilterColor to capsfilterRate as this is more appropriate.
Also I havent tested at all - just wrote on top of my head, I hope it will compile :D

```
source = gst_element_factory_make ("v4l2src", "source");
GstElement *capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "camera_caps");
conv = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace", "Colorconverter");
videorate = gst_element_factory_make("videorate", "videorate-element");
GstElement *capsfilterRate = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "video-rate");
videoenc = gst_element_factory_make("ffenc_mpeg4", "videoenc");
udpsink = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink");

// cap filter #1
GstCaps *caps = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw-yuv,format=(fourcc)YUY2,width=320,height=240,framerate=25/1");
g_object_set (capsfilter, "caps", caps, NULL);
gst_caps_unref(caps);//do not forget to unref - memoryleak!

// capfilter #2
GstCaps *capsRate = gst_caps_from_string ("video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=10/1");
g_object_set ( capsfilterRate, "caps", capsRate, NULL);
gst_caps_unref(capsRate);//again unref!

// Create the empty pipeline
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(udpsink),
             "host", "127.0.0.1",
             "port", 5000,
             NULL);

g_object_set (G_OBJECT ( source ), 
              "device", "/dev/video0", 
              NULL);

//proper adding to pipe
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), source, capsfilter, conv, videorate, capsfilterRate,  videoenc, udpsink, NULL);

//proper linking:
gst_element_link_many (source, capsfilter, conv, videorate, capsfilterRate,  videoenc, udpsink, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I am quite new to gstreamer and never understood caps properties. But your detailed explanation helped me to understand it. Thanks a ton again